# How to hide or disable json response in browser using angularjs $http.post method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, response

I want to hide my json response data using angularjs

```
$http.post("./rest/getMethodBack", parameter).then(function(response){
          console.log(response); 
});
```

the browser console will print like

```
{"name": "Anand", "Age":"25", "City": "Chennai"}
```

For understanding i have put `console.log` but in the chrome browser in networks i can find the response data completely

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlduY.jpg)

You can find the response output in the browser, i need to hide or disable it.

I tried putting `headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}` but doesn't work, can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You can not hide it, because this response is available to your code and it is  Addon which is showing you the response. If you are requesting then server need to give the response, you can try encrypting your data, so that no one can get what is actual data.

Comment: What do you exactly want. ? Do you want your data to be NOT visible in network tab??

Comment: @JinsPeter exactly data should not visible in network tab.

Comment: @[Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7924132/developer) Ok. That's not possible, go for encryption

Comment: @Developer Seems really crappy. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's the server returned response. If you want an empty response, you need to remove it on the server side, at the specified api endpoint.